# How to add flags to webdrive using JS?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to add this attribute 
chrome://flags/#mark-non-secure-as

Part of the webdriver

I saw that I can add with

```
var capabilities = webdriver.Capabilities.chrome();
```

Is it the right way ?

If yes which attribute do I need to add this attribute
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities

The value that I want to pass is Always mark Http as neural , Does it have any constant ?

var TestConfiguration = require("./globalConfiguration"),
    webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    proxy = require('selenium-webdriver/proxy');

```
module.exports = {

    createDriver: function () {
        var capabilities = webdriver.Capabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.chromeOptions =  {
            args: ['mark-non-secure-as=NEUTRAL']
        };
        var manualProxy = TestConfiguration.getParam(TestConfiguration.KEYS.PROXY);
        var proxyToSet = proxy.system();
        if (manualProxy) {
            proxyToSet = proxy.manual({http: manualProxy, https: manualProxy});
        }

        var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(capabilities).
            usingServer(TestConfiguration.getParam(TestConfiguration.KEYS.SELENIUM_HOST))
            .setProxy(proxyToSet)
            .build();
        return driver;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify whether you are using C# or Java version of the selenium driver but the code is basically the same either way.  The c# code below opens chrome with the attribute 'chrome://flags/#mark-non-secure-as' set.

You just need to create a ChromeOptions object set the desired options and pass it to the driver constructor.
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--mark-non-secure-as");

IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

I used version 3.3 of Webdriver.dll and the Chrome driver from: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started

Comment: I am using javascript

Comment: and the value that should be is NEUTRAL so How I can do it ?

Comment: For this parameter there are 3 values so how i can pass the right values? How i can know the values?